# Using Key Match to reference another node in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am looking to combine a single XML sheet with two "sections" of information, "Notes" and "Encounters". Each note has an *Extension ID* and each encounter also has an *Extension ID*.

The data is setup like such:

```
<Root>
  <Notes>
    <Note>
        <NoteText>
            <p>Text Paragraph 1</p>
            <p>Text Paragraph 2</p>
        </NoteText>
        <ExtensionID>123456</ExtensionID>
    </Note>
    <Note>
        <NoteText>
            <p>Text Paragraph 3</p>
        </NoteText>
        <ExtensionID>123456</ExtensionID>
    </Note>
    <Note>
        <NoteText>
            <p>Text Paragraph 4</p>
            <p>Text Paragraph 5</p>
        </NoteText>
        <ExtensionID>789012</ExtensionID>
    </Note>
  </Notes>
    <Encounter>
        <ExtensionID>123456</ExtensionID>
        <Date>2017-01-02</Date>
        <Author>Dr. George Smith</Author>
    </Encounter>
        <ExtensionID>798012</ExtensionID>
        <Date>2015-10-20</Date>
        <Author>Jenny Jones</Author>
    <Encounter>
<Root>
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
<Import>
    <Notes>
        <Note ExtensionID="123456">
            <NoteText>
                <p>Text Paragraph 1</p>
                <p>Text Paragraph 2</p>
                <p>Text Paragraph 3</p>
            <NoteText>
            <Author>Dr. George Smith</Author>
            <Date>2015-10-20</Date>
        </Note>
        <Note ExtensionID="789012">
            <NoteText>
                <p>Text Paragraph 4</p>
                <p>Text Paragraph 5</p>
            <NoteText>
            <Author>Jenny Jones</Author>
            <Date>2015-10-20</Date>
        </Note>
    <Notes>
<Import>
```

My Current XSLT is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">

      <Import>

      <Notes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Notes"/>
      </Notes>
  </Import>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name ="ExtID" match="Note" use="ExtensionID"/>


  <xsl:template match="Root/Notes">
    <xsl:for-each select="Note[count(.|key('ExtID',ExtensionID)[1]) = 1]">
      <Note>
        <xsl:attribute name="ExtensionID">

          <xsl:value-of select="ExtensionID"/>

        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('ExtID',ExtensionID)">
          <xsl:copy-of select="NoteText"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:for-each select="../../Encounters/Encounter[ExtensionID=key('ExtID',ExtensionID)]">
        <Author>
          <xsl:value-of select="Provider"/>        
        </Author>
        <Date>
            <xsl:value-of select="Date" />
        </Date>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </Note>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first part works, mostly, where it's grouping by Extension ID, but it's the associated Encounter info that I'm struggling with.

What I'm noticing is that it's not even going into the for-each loop with "../../Encounters/Encounter[ExtensionID=key('ExtID',ExtensionID)]". I'm nearly positive that I can't do what I want to do: use the key like some form of "not- variable", but I'm not sure what to try next.

Please note: I'm constrained by the software we use in my office to XSLT 1.0. I do not have access to 2.0 functions, nor am I able to install/upgrade or use a different engine than the one in Visual Studio.

Comment: Your XML is not well formed (You have an opening `<Notes>` tag, but no closing one for example). Also, the root element in your XML is `Root` but in your XSLT you are looking for `NoteRoot`. Because the XML is not well-formed, it is not clear whether this is a typo in your question or the actual problem, so you might want to correct your XML first. Thanks!

Comment: Total typo! Thanks for catching it. That's what I get for simplifying a bit too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a problem with this line...

```
<xsl:for-each select="../../Encounters/Encounter[ExtensionID=key('ExtID',ExtensionID)]">
```

Ignoring the fact you don't have `Encounters` in your XML, the "key" will return a `Note` node, when you just want the value of the `ExtensionID` for the current `Note`. So it should be this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="../../Encounters/Encounter[ExtensionID=current()/ExtensionID]">
```

Or, if you define another key like this...

```
<xsl:key name="EncID" match="Encounter" use="ExtensionID"/>
```

You can then do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('EncID', ExtensionID)">
```

Try this XSLT....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Import>
      <Notes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Notes"/>
      </Notes>
    </Import>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name ="ExtID" match="Note" use="ExtensionID"/>
  <xsl:key name="EncID" match="Encounter" use="ExtensionID"/>

  <xsl:template match="Notes">
    <xsl:for-each select="Note[count(.|key('ExtID',ExtensionID)[1]) = 1]">
      <Note ExtensionID="{ExtensionID}">
        <NoteText>
          <xsl:copy-of select="key('ExtID',ExtensionID)/NoteText/*"/>
        </NoteText>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('EncID', ExtensionID)">
          <Author>
            <xsl:value-of select="Author"/>        
          </Author>
          <Date>
           <xsl:value-of select="Date" />
          </Date>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Note>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Maybe you should reverse the logic of the XSLT though? Instead of doing grouping on the `Note` elements, start off by getting the `Encounter` elements, and then using the key to get the notes for them....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="ExtID" match="Note" use="ExtensionID"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Import>
      <Notes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Encounters/Encounter[key('ExtID', ExtensionID)]"/>
      </Notes>
    </Import>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Encounter">
    <Note ExtensionID="{ExtensionID}">
      <NoteText>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ExtID',ExtensionID)/NoteText/*"/>
      </NoteText>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Author|Date" />
    </Note>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The first suggestion worked great! Thanks for your quick response. I think the second option would be a great way to go, but I simplified my example to the point where it wouldn't really work, I think. Could you explain how the XSLT "knows" to match the Ext ID and EncID?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean... The ExtID and EncID are keys, and you use them to select nodes which match against a specified value. How XSLT does this behind the scenes, I am not sure....

Answer (score 1):

Define a second key for the cross-reference:

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="Encounter" use="ExtensionID"/>
```

then you can select

```
  <xsl:for-each select="key('ref',ExtensionID)">
    <Author>
      <xsl:value-of select="Provider"/>        
    </Author>
    <Date>
        <xsl:value-of select="Date" />
    </Date>

  </xsl:for-each>
```

instead of

```
  <xsl:for-each select="../../Encounters/Encounter[ExtensionID=key('ExtID',ExtensionID)]">
    <Author>
      <xsl:value-of select="Provider"/>        
    </Author>
    <Date>
        <xsl:value-of select="Date" />
    </Date>

  </xsl:for-each>
```